# Creating nouns from verbs

Tags: single-word-requests, grammar

Is there a general rule for creating a noun based on an action?

In the example below, there are two actions.

```
"Press button when you've resolved or gave up."
```

I'd like to express it using nouns like so:

```
"Press button upon resolution or XXX."
```

Is it as simple as "*giving up*" or is there a better way (in this particular case of "*giving up*")? Can that suggestion (if any) be made general?

Comment: Nounifying verbs is the basis of the [*gerund*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gerund).

Comment: Various verbs undergo "nouning" differently. The gerund (*-ing* form) is one (more common) of them. However, I don't think there's one single rule, formula or algorithm.

Comment: This is not a rule (hence my posting in comment) but "surrender" fits XXX quite well even though it doesn't follow any strict rule (if that's the case then "giving up" would be the answer). However, I think the verb form is clearly better and less belabored than the noun form. BTW you might want to rethink using those verbs: "resolve" usually doesn't stand alone and "gave" should be "given" to maintain paralellism. Why not "Press the button when you succeed or fail"? It is short and has a nice ring to it.

Comment: _quitting_ is an alternative to _giving up._ At any rate _Press button upon resolution or XXX_ does not sound colloquial.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In general, you have several options to use verb forms as nouns:

- the bare infinitive. *the **work** was done.*
- the gerund. ***Working** makes him happy.*
- a related noun that does not (in English) derive directly from the verb. *The **resolution** was passed.*

If no related noun exists, you can chose between the bare infinitive and the verb. Usually the difference in meaning is that the bare infinitive refers to a complete, whole, phenomenon, such as *work*, a nice *read*, a long *walk*.

Ok, as Janus Bahs Jacquet mentions, these bare infinitives may also exist on their own without actually being (linked to) the verb directly. I would guess however that it is certainly possible to *noun* hitherto *unnouned* verbs in this way. **Have's** and **have-not's** are derived from the verb, according to [etymonline](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?allowed_in_frame=0&search=have-not&searchmode=none), for instance.

Whether directly derived or not, at least the fact they have the exact *form* of teh infinitive can help as an identification. :)

The gerund indicates the *action* expressed by the verb, as in *I like reading, walking, working*.

Not all verbs react well to this kind of use, especially not the bare infinitive. *To be*, for instance has no problem when you refer to a *being*, but I would not know what a **be* would mean.

In your example, you can use the gerund without and problem; *giving up* is absolutely fine. 
There may be some nouns that express a similar meaning, but *giving up* will be readily understood.

Comment: _Work_, _read_, and _walk_ are not really infinitives—they're just nouns that are not derived from the verb, but happen to be identical to the verb stem. In older stages of English, they would have differed (cf. _breathe_ vs. _breath_). @Konrad This is just as in Swedish: some verbs have an underived corresponding noun (_att köpa_ <> _ett köp_), others use various nominalising endings (_att boka_ <> _en bokning_).

Comment: And why to the full infinitive? *He tried to leave.* Or *To dance, that is the ultimate poetry.*

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet I'm always flabbergasted and spooked at the same time when you post. I have this strong (and apparently very incorrect) view that nobody speaks Swedish (except for a few Swedes, 99% of whom don't care about the linguistical virtuosity). You're a diamond in the rough. :)